# How to replace multiple pipleline with comma using CSV file in Jmeter

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to replace multiple pipleline with comma  using CSV file in Jmeter.

I am using Groovy script. Below is the body data of Jmeter. I am getting multiple values from CSV files and not able to use replaceAll function body data in Jmeter. 
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: where is your groovy script?

Comment: We can use like that "TemplateIDs": "${TemplateID1}.replaceAll("|",",")",    But replaceAll is not working in bodydata.

Comment: You tried `"${TemplateID1.replaceAll("|", ",")}",`

Comment: I tried above, but that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) in order to evaluate the Groovy code in [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler body
2. You need to escape `|`
3. You need to escape `,`
4. You need to escape `\`

Assuming all above the relevant `__groovy()` function syntax would be:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('TemplateID1').replaceAll('\\\|'\,'\,'),)}
```

[image: JMeter Groovy Replace char in string]

Also be aware that there is a [__strReplace() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) which can also do what you need, in this case the syntax would be:

```
${__strReplace(${TemplateID1},\\|,\,,)}
```

If you don't have this function it can be installed as a part of "
Custom JMeter Functions" bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T. It works fantastic and you solved my issue. Thanks a alot.

Answer (score 0):

replaceAll accepts a regex. you need to escape the pipe char.

```
replaceAll("\\|", ",")
```

I tested this in plain groovy and it works. not sure about jmeter integration.

Comment: It works in plain groovy, but its not working there(Body Data). Its giving something like that."TemplateIDs": "1|2|3|5.replaceAll("\|", ",")",

Comment: are you able to make any groovy usage this way? for example substring(0,2). Not sure if this is a replace issue or simply that groovy-jmeter integration is not done the way you expected it to be.

Comment: Dimitri T answered the perfectly. Please see his answer. Thanks Gagan.